# Find all repo branches with the ruby-git gem, without cloning the whole repo

Tags: ruby, git, branch

I wish to check out which branches exists for a given repository. I know how to do this by cloning the full repository with the [ruby-git gem](https://github.com/ruby-git/ruby-git):

```rb
Git.clone("https://user@bitbucket.org/my_repo.git", "my_repo", :path => "/my/repos")

g = Git.open("/my/repos/my_repo")

g.branches.each do |branch|
  puts branch.name
end
```

But if my objective is to simply check out what branches exists it feels wrong to clone the full repository. Isn't there a way to clone metadata only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git ls-remote --heads https://user@bitbucket.org/my_repo.git` prints all the branches in the remote repository without cloning the repository. Note that the remote repository may reject `git ls-remote` for safety.

There is an example on [ruby-git gem](https://github.com/ruby-git/ruby-git),

```
Git.ls_remote('https://github.com/ruby-git/ruby-git.git') # returns a hash containing the available references of the repo.
```

So you can try

```
Git.ls_remote('https://user@bitbucket.org/my_repo.git')
```

If `Git.ls_remote` does not support `--heads`, the refs that start with `refs/heads/` are what you want.